# How to Retrieve the EXISTING_FILE_ID when Integrating google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
   .setResultCallback(idCallback);

How to get the EXISTING_FILE_ID in above code For google drive integration.
I have to Retrieve the file Stored on google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(GoogleApiClient client)
```

to get root DriveFolder first.